# creating structures in c

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 80

typedef struct
{
    char nome[MAX];
    int num_bi;
    char *data_entrada;
}Paciente;


typedef struct lnode *List;
typedef struct lnode
{
    Paciente pac;
    List next;
}List_node;
```

I am declaring these structures and have three errors

conflicting types for 'Paciente'

redefinition of 'struct lnode'

confliting types for 'List_node'

can anyone help me

Comment: Those typedefs are fine. How are you trying to use them?

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
typedef struct Pacientes
{
    char nome[MAX];
    int num_bi;
    char *data_entrada;
}Paciente;

typedef struct NodeLists
{
    Paciente pac;
    List next;
}NodeList;
```